Biology of a Planet Sized Lifeform
This is also part of the sci-fi thing I'm working on, a planet sized lifeform.
The planet sized biological creature belongs to the "Ancestral Elves" species, and is also the capital planet of the Origin Elves civilization. It is based on the planet "New Origin", a super earth larger than Earth and spins faster. The bulk of this creature's mass is the planet's inner mantle and core, while the outer mantle and crust has been occupied biologically, with root-like structures reaching hundreds of kilometers deep and harness the heat of the planet itself.
This creature uses both chemistry and nuclear based power production, it body is half organic and half inorganic with the inorganic parts printed out with secretion of inorganic material.
The creature is plant like, but with animal, fungi and bacteria attributes, it's genome is much larger than the genome of life on Earth, containing compacted genetic information of hundreds of thousands of species. It's biochemistry is vastly different from Earth creatures with its protein altered and genome composed of molecules more stable and efficient than DNA, and it's skin made of graphene like material.
This creature is extremely large with it's body exceeding 15000km in diameter, structure on its surface taller than the height of it's atmosphere, like hundreds of kilometers, and tentacles reaching geostationary orbit and beyond, effectively functioning like space elevators and are stabilized by centrifugal force. The creature has a ring composed of both organic and inorganic formed in it's geostationary orbit, this ring is basically a megastructure around the lifeform.
The creature is fully colonized by the Origin Elves, and cities were constructed on it's surface. This creature is highly intelligent, it's quantum and chemistry based brain is more powerful than billions of human brains combined, it's growth is so extreme that it's printing out semi-organic spaceships and constructing a dyson sphere around the star within the star system where it belongs.
But here is a problem: can such a creature even exist, even if it's engineered, will evolution select such a creature instead of multiple smaller lifeforms.

This question is similar to: Is a planet sized creature possible?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Nuclear Hoagie: Of course this question is different. The linked one concentrates on the "possibilities of existence" (because of size, weight, gravity, energy hunger etc.) while this question here is focused on the "evolutionary success" of such creatures, given they do exist. It can be considered a follow-up question if you want. But not a duplicate. There is no editing of the question needed, in my opinion.

In fiction, it definitely does exist. In Cameron's Avatar, the flora of the planet Pandora is, to some extent, a single organism; in F. Herbert + B. Ransom's The Jesus Incident, the flora of Pandora (no relation) is mostly a "sentient kelp", whose immune system is the deadly fauna roaming the continents of the planet.

You've given a long list of constraints, each of which makes the planet increasingly improbable - that's not to say it's impossible, but the improbabilities multiply alarmingly. How do you mean "will evolution select such a creature..."? If you say it exists, then it does. We have no evidence for: 1) Any structure strong enough to reach orbit without collapsing under it's own gravity. 2) An organic printer evolving.

Cont.: 3) A mineral brain evolving/being able to be printed by an organic creature. 4) A molecule more stable and efficient than DNA (this is an odd one, more stable decreases the chance of mutation - and therefore evolution. Not sure what efficiency means in this case) This to me, seems to be a prime candidate for science-fiction, no reason it can't be written about. Not sure what you need from us. What is the actual question here?

@Escapeddentalpatient I know a backwater planet, on the rim of a galaxy, where a colony of bipedal primates live in symbiosis with a sort of silicon-based mycelium. It has grown to fully entangle all the continental platforms of the planet, even projecting some hyphae over the oceans. It functions as a sort of global nervous system for the primates, who have more or less completely surrendered their individual brains to it. How implausible d'you reckon that is?

@Escapeddentalpatient. The question is: can an organism of such monstrous size and abilities as depicted by the OP succeed in the Darwinian struggle for existence?

What's it succeeding against? What's the shared environment? What are it's competitors, rate of reproduction, reproductive strategy (large numbers and parental abandonment Vs small numbers and parental care). What is it's evolutionary history (i.e. what did its ancestors look like a million years ago - what were its competitors and environment then). @FrançoisJurain It's a science-fiction question asking for scientific judgement of it success - there's a mismatch of expectations here.

I agree with @Escapeddentalpatient. that you're not asking the actual question. Insofar as we understand science, no, such a creature cannot exist. We don't have the tech to engineer a planet-sized anything, so it's impossible to answer "even if it's engineered?" and whether or not evolution would "select" such a lifeform depends on whether we're talking about mice or elephants, right? It feels like you're asking us to either evaluate or approve an idea and we don't really have a procedure to do that. But, we've answered Qs about planet-sized creatures before, so, what is the actual question?

You're also giving us very little information about the creature itself, internally, biologically, focusing mostly on its outer layer. Where is its brain located, in what way is it actually a creature and not an intelligent printer? Where does it come from? And please firstly decide whether or not it's engineered, as we can't do that for you.

I was the last close vote and I think it's important you understand why. You're getting a smattering of answers from predominantly new users who don't really understand Stack Exchange themselves (or, if they do, shame on them). Answers range from "here's a problem..." to a treatise on evolution that's a non-answer to "here's a solution to a problem someone else mentioned." That's literally the reason Stack Exchange wants poorly designed questions closed as quickly as possible, damn the OP's feelings. Per the [tour], this is not a discussion forum, but that's basically what you're asking for.

Nerve signals travel about 0.5 to 2.0 m/s in small non-myelinated fibers (2–4 µm in diameter); 3 to 15 m/s in myelinated fibers of the same size; and as fast as 120 m/s in large myelinated fibers (up to 20 µm in diameter). Given the size of your planet, if the creature can meaningful interact with itself, that makes its thoughts slow, lots of its hardware dedicated to syncing signals, or seperated into regional minds that share memories with the total. And that is its fastest part. Chemistry exchange and energy transfer would be even slower.
40.000 m / 15 = 45 minutes for a thought to go around the world. A meteor strikes and 20 minutes later, the other side of the planet says "ouch".. All this comes in parallels, a sort of planetwide autism of constant, input that comes to late.. as such it might even not percieve fast events that happen in the merge.

One reason more to have some little creatures come to help with "fast processing" of stuff. I like the idea of the slow brained planet. Nice thought!

That is giving a supposition that it has some centralised brain. Where is the brain of a tree? A brain working with quantum entaglement could transport messages quickly maybe? Quantum entanglement goes way over my head though and I've seen articles saying it can't send information faster than light even though it is faster than light, but that's probably for us measly humans with our technology, not some engineered/evolved quantum brain.

Of course when I say supposition of centralised brain it gives the option of a distributed brain, as in you don't necessarily need it to say ouch in 20 minutes if the meteor strike site brain already says ouch, like even our human body functions without the brain involved in all decisions like when white blood cell detects some virus

You have given so much background information, that I was very convinced that such a creature can exist, even though it is highly unlikely we will ever encounter such a thing in our universe. It seems so consistent and plausible, because you provided so much detail which provides enough "counter information" to tackle any doubtful thoughts about it.
I applaude you and say well done! Good author's job! Don't forget: It is your fantasy/Sci-Fi story. If you say this creature exists, it exists. Period. If the reader thinks this is unrealistic, then he is invited to not read any further. This does not make your story implausible.
Think of the Marvel Universe. Do I believe there can be a creature like Thanos, an ARC-Reactor like Iron-Man sports on his chest or some kind of Eternals being born out of a planet in our universe? - No. But, am I convinced, that in the universe of these stories such things can and do exist? - Yes! Of course I am. Because I like those stories.
Now to the hypothetical part of your question concerning evolutionary selection of a creature: I would drop the idea that evolution is some kind of "rule" or inherent force in the universe which a creature has to fulfill or abide to, to thrive or it will die out. It is more like the other way around. If a creature thrives, for whatever reasons there might be, it is said to be "evolutionary successful".
If you want an explanation for the evolutionary success of your planet creature... just invent one, like you did with all the other aspects of it!
It could very well be plausible, that this creature is one of a kind in the whole universe. So aspects like reproduction, commonly associated to evolutionary success, would not even apply in this case.
It could also be plausible that this creature can only exist because of a symbiosis (also a common concept in evolutionary theories) with the smaller lifeforms living on it.
It could also be, that the creature is an engineered one, why not. If it is, then the question of evolutionary success would not even be valid, because it was artificially created. In this case, to exist over an extended period of time, it just has to be able to "live" and not be destroyed by other factors like heat, cold, impact, being eaten by other creatures, etc. If it is also able to fulfill other aspects of evolutionary theory, like reproduction, then all the better. I cross fingers the planet creature will find a proper mate and produce lots of baby-planet-creatures :D
I concentrated on "scientific" explanations here. But there could also be spiritual factors involved. Like a god created that creature or the creature is supposed to be some kind of god itself.

As someone mentioned, if the hardware of its neuronal signalling is akin to ours, it would be very slow-brained. This could cause plot issues.
So, let its peripheral nervous system work via light signals. Tons of organic and inorganic things produce light, tons of materials reflect light, and tons of biological things are capable of being excited by light. There could be a centralized brain that receives light signals from all over the planet and receives it all with light-sensitive receptors, before processing it.
I think that a "fiber-optic" peripheral nervous system is not so implausible from the evolutionary standpoint if we envision it as evolving later, perhaps with the guidance of a previous, already-intelligent version of the creature.
Who knows, maybe the creature began as a species on a planet much like us? They evolved to be more and more intelligent, with greater and greater planetary infrastructure. Eventually, they assimilated; from a species of individuals, to becoming a hive-mind, before becoming a god-mind. Later on, the god-mind just integrated itself into the infrastructure of planet, merging with it gradually.
